# Map Multiple Controls to one Method

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I know in the .Net framework you can map any controls events to a singular method, as if you wanted to map a column of buttons in a GridView to one method, you could.

In VBA i have since forgotten this information.  Could someone help me out in how i can map a Forms' Control(s) to one method in the Forms Code-Behind?

### Current OnClick Events, to be consolidated

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
    CloseForm Me
End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click()
    CloseForm Me
End Sub
```

There are at least two of these methods per form.  On some there are 3 or 4 for various Events but they all have the same body, one line pointing to a global method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. You can set up the form so that it receives the click events  and check the screen.active control or you can set the event line on the property sheet for each control to a function. Frequently, people who are not familiar with the ease of MS Access go a long way around, which is why it is useful to say what you wish to do, there is often an easier way and often a way that does not involve code at all.

On the click line of the property sheet for the control:

```
=Menu_Or_Exit([Name],"cmdClose")
```

of course you could pass Me as form, but I have found [Name] to be very useful in a number of ways.

An excerpt from the function:

```
        Case "cmdClose"
            DoCmd.Close acForm, FormName
            CheckMainMenu
```

You can keep a menu form, a menu subform, or just copy the button from form to form.

Comment: I have around 10-15 forms....and, at least, two buttons on each form do the same thing `CloseForm Me` and i figured it would be easier if i had a Module Global method that i could map the Buttons.OnClick event to.  Ill Revise my Q Post to show you the destination Method for these controls Click Event

Comment: so understand the parts `Menu_Or_Exit` is the method name, `[Name]` is a directive synonymouse with `Form.Name`, and of course `"cmdClose"` would be the control name.  So in theory i could lop off `"cmdClose"` parameter and just pass the method the `[Name]` parameter and be done with it?

Comment: Yes, you could. The above was a menu function with other possible buttons and actions, for example, cmdHide. There was no need to tell the user I was hiding, not closing the form :)

Comment: Was noticing that the method, after being placed in a Module was not showing up in the Expression Builder.  Is there a readon why a `Public Sub` in a Module would not show up in Expression Builder?  Or does it only look for Parametered Methods?

Comment: Function, not sub. You can only refer to functions in this way.

Comment: ok that would be the reason it wasnt showing up.....just a Null return Function but still has to be declared as a Funtion?

Comment: I am afraid so. I think it relates back to macros.

Comment: Last question in regards to mapping.  Can the Function/Macro be Public on the Form itself or must it always be a Module-Level method?